# Edit control in loop

Tags: c, winapi

Please l want to ask how l can add multiple edit control using for loop. I have tried it but it only creates one and increases the size of the edit box instead of creating different individual edit boxes. However, l want to create multiple kind of edit boxes where the user can enter a single character per box. Am using native C Win32 language Any idea, l appreciate.

There's no error report. It compiles well.
I mean it only creates one edit box and keep increasing the size of that one instead of creating different individual edit boxes.

All protocols observed...

```
HWND hedit;
case WM_CREATE:
{
   for(int i=0;i<50;i  ){
   hedit=CreateWindowEx (NULL, TEXT("Edit"),NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_LEFT,0,0,10,10,....);
}
return 0
```

l still tried setting the x coordinate to i but nothing works.
thanks.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess, what errors your code contains, without seeing your code. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *I have tried it but it only creates one*. We have no idea what **it** is. Please read the site help and improve the question.

Comment: Please, for the love of God, don't post code in comments. Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30098084/edit) option and update your question. Irrespective of that, why do you assume to see several distinct edit controls, when you create them all **in the same place**?

Comment: @llnspectable: Sorry and forgive my mistakes. But please help me out with any alternative if you can.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you put all editcontrols at the same position. Try to set them on different positions and maybe hold the handles in an array or something like this. Also the for loop is not correct (i++ is missed).

try something like:

```
int height = 20;
int width = 60;
HWND edtits[50];
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){ 
    edtits[i] = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"EDIT", L"InitText", WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT, 0, i * (height + 2), width, height, parrent_HWND, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But l want to ask if the edit control is appropriate cos l want to create a kind of spreedsheet for data entries or is there any other api function to use?

Comment: Hmm maybe a ListView with editcontrols could solve it. here some links which can help you: Winapi overview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Winapi Controllib: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems